# <hr/> tag should increase size dynamically based on text

Tags: css, dynamic, width

I have `<hr/>` tag, that should be dynamically increase its size based on text below to `<hr/>` tag.

```
<div class="outer">
<hr class="line"/>
The above line should be match with this sentence.
</div>
```

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 3):

Add `inline-block` to outer div

Example 1:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
          <hr class="line"/>
          The above line should be with this sentence.
      </div>
```

Example 2:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
          <hr class="line"/>
          short text
      </div>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if you find your solution in it by tiking the check mark under vote

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `width: fit-content` to the `outer` class.

```css
.outer {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<hr class="line"/>
The above line should be match with this sentence.
</div>
```

**Edit**: For better browser support, you can use `display: table` instead.

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<hr class="line"/>
The above line should be match with this sentence.
</div>
```

Comment: Just want to note, that this is currently not supported in our best friends Edge and Internet Explorer

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert it's even not supported in Firefox without prefix

Comment: Great. Thank you.